# Inner Join with subquery and or

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a chat with several conversations and have a task to extract latest messages from each conversation.
By conversation I mean messages from or to particular user. (It is defned by `fromid` or `toid` column).

My plan:

1) Extract id's of conversations

2) Extract messages themselves

Based on anwers to similar questions here, I build this query that failed to execute ("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `fromid` != 4 LIMIT 10) table2 ON (table2.VALIDID = `support_chat_message' at line 1")

My query is

```
SELECT `fromid`, `toid`, `message`, `sendat`, `messageid` 
FROM `support_chat_messages` INNER JOIN
             (SELECT  `fromid` as VALIDID 
             FROM  `support_chat_messages`  
             GROUP BY  `fromid`
             WHERE `fromid` != 4 LIMIT 10) table2 
        ON  (table2.VALIDID = `support_chat_messages`.`fromid`) 
        OR (table2.VALIDID = `support_chat_messages`.`toid`) ORDER BY `messageid`
```

Some explanations:

1) I select `fromid` and group them via same field to get conversations (=users ids). Users id are named VALIDID

2) Where `fromid` != 4 mean that not messages from me (only other users id).

3) Limit 10 - no more than 10 conversations.

4) I search the table support_chat_messages for message that was send from selected user (`table2.VALIDID = support_chat_messages.fromid`) or to selected user (`table2.VALIDID = support_chat_messages.toid`)

What is the problem with query?

How to limit query? I need to get the latest message from each conversation. IF I put limit 1 at the end I will get just latest conversation, but not 1 from each.

Do you know how to optimize it? I will refresh every 2 sec and I such query will seriously load the system. I have an idea to use groupby (fromid or toid) without join, but not sure that such expression is valid.

Thanks for help.

Here's a fiddle of same.  sqlfiddle.com/#!2/796c4/4/0

Desired result would like this...

Conversations are (7 and 4), (6 and 4), (5 and 4), (2 and 4) For each top messages are (22), (21), (20), (18)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/796c4/4/0

Comment: Desider result: (fromid, toid, messageid): (7,4,22),(6,4,21),(5,4,20),(2,4,18)

Comment: Conversations are (7 and 4), (6 and 4), (5 and 4), (2 and 4)
For each top messages are (22), (21), (20), (18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM support_chat_messages x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT fromid
            , MAX(sendat) max_sendat 
         FROM support_chat_messages 
        WHERE fromid != 4
        GROUP
           BY fromid
     ) y
    ON y.fromid = x.fromid 
   AND y.max_sendat = x.sendat;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/796c4/6

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to optimize it somehow?

Comment: An index on (fromid,sendat)

Comment: How to consider situation when fromid and toid are reversed?

Comment: Update your fiddle and desired result set